# How to vectorize an operation in 2 dimensional matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I want to eliminate the for loop from the code below and vectorize it, but it is a 2 dimensional operation. Can you please help me.

```
for i=1:10
    savingsFull(i,:) = distances(i,9)+distances(9,knnIdx(i,:))-distances(i,knnIdx(i,:));
end
```

here, "distances" is a 10x10 symmetric matrix and "knnIdx" is a 10x2 matrix as below:

```
 1    10
 2    10
 3     8
 4     8
 5     4
 6     5
 7     2
 8     4
 9     8
10     1
```

"savingsFull" is also a 10x2 matrix.

Comment: use `bsxfun` to vectorize

Comment: I treated all matrices as a vector and applied the formula on it.

Answer (score 1):

Following code should help:

```
savingsFull = distances(:, [9 9]) + [distances(9, knnIdx(:, 1)).', distances(9, knnIdx(:, 2)).'] - [diag(distances(:, knnIdx(:, 1))), diag(distances(:, knnIdx(:, 2)))]
```

If first column of knnIdx are consequent numbers from 1 to 10, then you can simplify to

```
savingsFull = distances(:, [9 9]) + [distances(9, knnIdx(:, 1)).', distances(9, knnIdx(:, 2)).'] - [diag(distances), diag(distances(:, knnIdx(:, 2)))]
```

Comment: would you please describe me what the dot operator does in distances(9, knnIdx(:, 1)).'  
Thanks

Comment: @remo, the difference between `'` and `.'` operators is that `.'` transposes a matrix and `'` only changes dimensions. So there is a simple relation between them: `A' = conj(A.');`. So `distances(9, knnIdx(:, 1)).'` leads to a column-vector instead of row-vector. So, assuming that `distance` is real-valued, there should be no difference between `'` and `.'`.

Comment: Seems like I've swapped definitions in previous comment. Sorry =) Anyway you can check matlab reference for both of them.
[ctranspose](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html),  [transpose](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html)